# Own iOS MDM Server

Tags: python, http, daemon, mdm

**Interlude**
We are trying to create our own Apple iOS MDM Server, so that we can push configuration profiles to our own iOS devices. We do not seem to understand very well the steps to have such server up and running. We have already an apple enterprise account, and our own yosemite OSX server running.

In the apple documentation they talk about the need to develop a profile service, which is an HTTP-based daemon that manages iOS-based device connections.

**The Question**
Is it required to do this trough a daemon based script/application or is there a workaround to reuse the MDM's server application when creating our own solution?

All info is being very appreciated,

**Link to documentation**
[Apple Profile Server Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/profile-service/profile-service.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505-CH2-SW2)

Regards,
Alexander.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend utilizing the 'Profile Manager' built into OS X Server rather than rolling your own.  The documentation isn't a lot better but the steps are more straightforward.

The 'Profile Manager' application will automatically create the profiles you need.

Comment: Indeed the 'Profile Manager' is very straightforward and all, but what we actually need is to be able to integrate mdm into another system we run, therefor we are still looking for a solution that does not require using the graphical interface of the 'Profile manager'. Are you familiar with another kind of solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not, sorry.